# How to remove product url in product review in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am getting a lot of google crawl errors stating that it's find the following url types in my Magento installation:
catalog/product/view/id/97/

I narrowed this down and found this is occurring in customer product reviews. Where the title of the customer review is linked back to the product page. I have SEO friendly URL's enabled, but for some reason these links aren't being translated to friendly urls. I am using the MIRASVIT SEO module.

I just want to be able to remove the linkback from the review title back to the product page. I would appreciate any help pointing me to the right direction where I can remove it.

Comment: Have you tried `System > Config > Advanced > Mage_Tag > Disable > Save` ?

Comment: Yes Mage_Tag is already disabled

Comment: Can you find the file `local.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to Disable the Product Tag from the Panel by

```
System > Config > Advanced > Mage_Tag > Disable > Save
```

And if you don't succeed. Then you shall disable it directly by using this in your `local.xml` file

```
<remove name="product_tag_list" />
```

**Note :** Clear you cache once you update the local.xml file or try in incognito window from your browser

Comment: Neither of these makes any difference.

Comment: I've managed to find the source of the problem in app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/review/product/view/list.phtml

There is this link
<a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewUrl($_review->getId()) ?>"><span property="v:itemreviewed"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_review->getTitle()) ?></span></a> <?php echo $this->__('Review by <span property="v:reviewer">%s</span>', $this->htmlEscape($_review->getNickname())) ?>

I guess getReviewUrl is causing the issue. This is part of the Ultimo theme by infortis